# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"scoo.....missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a partial form for create and update...for the new it render the partial but when going for the edit one I keep getting this error

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Scoopes#edit
no route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"scoopes", :id=>nil, :user_name=>#<Scoope id: 11, name: "asdsada", user_id: 3, created_at: "2016-08-07 20:37:52", updated_at: "2016-08-07 20:37:52">} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I search for an answer from old questions but no one solved my problem...the form is for creating scoopes....

the assosiaction between scoope and users is :

```
scoope belong_to user
and user has_many scoopes
```

here is my scoope controller:

```
class ScoopesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
  before_action :set_scoope, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :index]
  before_action :owned_scoope, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @scoopes = @user.scoopes.all
  end

  def show
    @scoope = @user.scoopes.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @scoope = current_user.scoopes.build
  end

  def create
    @scoope = current_user.scoopes.build(scoope_params)
    if @scoope.save
        redirect_to scoope_path(current_user.user_name, @scoope)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @scoope = @user.scoopes.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @scoope = @user.scoopes.find(params[:id])
    if @scoope.update(scoope_params)
        redirect_to scoope_path(@user, @scoope)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @scoope = @user.scoopes.find(params[:id])
    @scoope.destroy
    redirect_to scoopes_path
  end

  private

  def scoope_params
    params.require(:scoope).permit(:name)
  end

  def set_scoope
    @user = User.find_by(user_name: params[:user_name])
  end
  def owned_scoope
    unless @user == current_user
        flash[:danger] = "this scope dont belong to you"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

here is my partial form(I think maybe the problem somehow related to the edit path because when I try yo replace scoope with edit_scoope_path then it render the form under the edit page..but it will not solve my whale problem because it is a partial):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 formm">
    <%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @scoope %>
    <div class="well">
      <%= form_for @scoope do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %><br/>
          <%= f.text_area :name, rows: 6, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary'  %> <%= link_to "Back", :back, class: "btn btn-danger" unless current_page?(scoopes_path) %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my routes for scoopes:

```
               scoopes GET    /:user_name/scoopes(.:format)               scoopes#index
                     POST   /:user_name/scoopes(.:format)               scoopes#create
          new_scoope GET    /:user_name/scoopes/new(.:format)           scoopes#new
         edit_scoope GET    /:user_name/scoopes/:id/edit(.:format)      scoopes#edit
              scoope GET    /:user_name/scoopes/:id(.:format)           scoopes#show
                     PATCH  /:user_name/scoopes/:id(.:format)           scoopes#update
                     PUT    /:user_name/scoopes/:id(.:format)           scoopes#update
                     DELETE /:user_name/scoopes/:id(.:format)           scoopes#destroy
```

my scoope table:

```
create_table "scoopes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "user/registrations" }
root "posts#index" 
scope '/:user_name' do
 resources :scoopes
end
get ':user_name', to: 'profiles#show', as: :profile  
get ':user_name/edit', to: 'profiles#edit', as: :edit_profile  
patch ':user_name/edit', to: 'profiles#update', as: :update_profile  
................
```

Comment: please post routes.rb

Comment: Does your console log show that an `id` is being passed when you make the edit call?

Comment: @Deepak I add routes you can see it now

Comment: @MarsAtomic If you talking about this here it is.. Parameters:

{"user_name"=>"Sam Abunu",
 "id"=>"11"}   that The id that display before the error in the log

Comment: @Tobias Thank u for the the improvment

Answer (score 1):

Your call is failing because you're working with a [nested route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), as defined by the `scoope belongs to user` relationship.

In `routes.rb`, you can set up ReSTful routing between `user` and `scoope` like so:

```
resources :users do
  resources :scoopes
end
```

This notation should give you the nested route you need:

```
edit_user_scoope_path
```

To organize the nested object under `user_name`, try:

```
scope "/:user_name" do
  resources :posts
end
```

This should give you a route like this:

```
edit_scoope GET /:user_name/scoopes/:id/edit(.:format) scoopes#edit
```

Comment: ok but I want user_name instead of user_id in the routes and here it gave user_id instead

Comment: also I dont want user/:user_name/scoopes/:id...If you notice my url in routes is :user_name/scoopes/:id because the scoopes is related to user profile url ...  
so for example my profile url is localhost:3000/Sam%20Abunu and if I want to check the the related scoopes I pass localhost:3000/Sam%20Abunu/scoopes but in your example it will change all my plan...!!

Comment: still this method not working...I found another method that work well without changing my routes.. I add this <%= form_for @scoope, :url => @scoope.persisted? ? scoope_path(@scoope.user.user_name, @scoope) : scoopes_path(current_user.user_name)  do |f| %>, anyway thank you for trying to help...you method give me some new things that I was not aware before...so thanks again

Comment: The second example should give you exactly what you want, so what do you mean by "this method not working?"

Comment: not worked for me and the form did not work also it gives me this two thing in the routes, 1-  user_scoopes GET    /users/:user_id/scoopes ..... 2- scoopes GET    /:user_name/scoopes ... as well as it gives me a new user routes with id which i dont want....all what I want is stay with only scope "/:user_name" do
  resources :posts
end without adding any routes and to fix the form

Comment: I see. Well, I'm glad you found something that worked for you. I would ask, however, that you clearly state all of your requirements in your questions rather than relying on readers to infer your meaning based on routes. Clarity would save everyone some time in the future.

Comment: I thought my question was clear but will ensure that it will be clearer in the fututre, T,Y ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies with your `routes.rb` file. You can add nested routes like below:

```
resources :users do
  resources :scoopes
end
```

that will output urls like below.From this output you can clearly see that the path will be `user_scoope_path(current_user, @scoope)` .

```
                                                                                                                                             scoopes#index
                                                            POST     /users/:user_id/scoopes(.:format)                                          scoopes#create
                                            new_user_scoope GET      /users/:user_id/scoopes/new(.:format)                                      scoopes#new
                                           edit_user_scoope GET      /users/:user_id/scoopes/:id/edit(.:format)                                 scoopes#edit
                                                user_scoope GET      /users/:user_id/scoopes/:id(.:format)                                      scoopes#show
                                                            PATCH    /users/:user_id/scoopes/:id(.:format)                                      scoopes#update
                                                            PUT      /users/:user_id/scoopes/:id(.:format)                                      scoopes#update
                                                            DELETE   /users/:user_id/scoopes/:id(.:format)                                      scoopes#destroy
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok but I want user_name instead of user_id in the routes and here it gave user_id instead

Comment: Ohh my bad, you can change your `routes.rb` like below:
   ` resources :users, :key => :user_name do
      resources :scoopes
    end `
and then call like `user_scoope_path(current_user.user_name, @scoope)`

Comment: I didn't test it but should work fine.Remember that in your show action you should use `@scoope = @user.scoopes.find(params[:user_name])`

Comment: still have user_id but also that not what I want...I dont want user/:user_name/scoopes/:id...If you notice my url in routes is :user_name/scoopes/:id because the scoopes is related to user profile url

Comment: so for example my profile url is http://localhost:3000/Sam%20Abunu and if I want to check the the related scoopes I pass http://localhost:3000/Sam%20Abunu/scoopes/ but in your example it will change all my plan...!!

Comment: still this method not working...I found another method that work well without changing my routes.. I add this <%= form_for @scoope, :url => @scoope.persisted? ? scoope_path(@scoope.user.user_name, @scoope) : scoopes_path(current_user.user_name)  do |f| %>, anyway thank you for trying to help...you method give me some new things that I was not aware before...so thanks again